# coloring a crosstab summary field based on some conditions

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

Is there a way to color a crosstab summary field based on some conditions. I tried on `Highlighting Expert` but cannot perform an `OR`. Tried also on `Format Field/Font` but not able to see the summary field.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks

**Update**

```
if (CurrentFieldValue <= 8 and instr({ROperationalData.RTDESC},"HOBE") > 0) then crRed else 
if (CurrentFieldValue <= 11.6 and instr({ROperationalData.RTDESC},"DAVIE") > 0) then crRed else
if (CurrentFieldValue <= 11 and instr({ROperationalData.RTDESC},"MIAMI") > 0) then crRed else
if (CurrentFieldValue <= 11.7 and instr({ROperationalData.RTDESC},"LANTANA") > 0) then crRed
```

right now it is just evaluating the first condition `CurrentFieldValue <= 8` but it is not taking in consideration the value of `{ROperationalData.RTDESC}` so it is marking red everything <= 8

[image]

Comment: If you select the cells you want to format and hit `Format Field` you can enter any kind of formatting formulas you like by referencing the `CurrentFieldValue` variable. Like `if CurrentFieldValue>1000 then CrRed else CrNoColor`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: that function worked for part of my condition, but this one also make reference to the group value. See my updated post